# SWT browser not rendering until shell resize

Tags: java, browser, swt

```
        Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);    
        browser.setUrl("localhost");

        browser.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void completed(ProgressEvent event) {
                shell.redraw();//useless                }

            @Override
            public void changed(ProgressEvent event) {

            }
        });



        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }

        display.dispose();

    }
```

I need resize window for displaying page!! the line "while (!shell.isDisposed())" is ugly. 
How display page without resizing ?

Comment: I don't have any answer for you, but I really recommend you to use JavaFX which is the new java standard to build GUI (I used to use SWT too, but trust me JavaFX is 1000 times better...)

Comment: Here is a webview example if you want to give a look at JavaFX : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/1510__JavaFX_WebView.htm

Comment: Thank You, but i have no the choice of API!

Comment: @ShellCode in my experience I find true native controls far more usable than "native-like" look and feel.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou in my experience, I don't use java to make native applications :) The only point that makes java a good language is its portability. If you need/prefer native access, languages such as c++ are more suitable ;) (in my opinion)

Comment: Which layout does the shell use?

Comment: @user2890095 I have executed it and its working fine without resizing. And i am assuming that you are using some layout on shell.

Comment: Yes I am using FillLayout. If i run without layout, it doen't work.